# Вставить условие в запрос PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, запрос

Хочу использовать такой PDO запрос, но выдает ошибку:

```
$and = 'AND `status` = 1';
$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `money` = :m AND date(`date`) = '2016-08-11' :and");
$res->execute(array(':m' => 10, ':and' => $and));
...
```

Как правильно подставить строку в запрос?

Comment: date(`date`) - это что у вас?

Comment: @user193361 это поле даты.

Comment: @user193361 нельзя

Comment: еще кавычки не хватает: `prepare('SELECT`

Comment: Ставлю минус за отвратительное оформление вопроса. Мало того что код не рабочий, так он и вовсе не отражает реальный запрос, который надо исполнить

Answer (score 4):

[Подставить кусок SQL через плейсхолдер нельзя](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#like)

Так что придется городить гуанокод

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `money` = :m AND date(`date`) = '2016-08-11'";
if ($and) {
    $sql .= ' AND `status` = 1';
}
$pdo->prepare($sql);
$res->execute(array(':m' => 10));
```

Comment: а если у меня в конце запроса стоит, например "GROUP BY..."?

Comment: значит банальная работа со строками будет чуть сложнее.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью данного метода вы не сможете вставить строку $and в запрос, данная конструкция сделана для того, чтобы подставлять параметры.

Вы должны отлично понимать, что при подобном небезопасном использовании функций для безопасного построения запроса вы открываете рай для хакера, который изучает SQL-инъекции. Сначала вы подставляете одну строку, потом другую, собираете весь запрос через строковые функции, не замечаете ошибки в безопасности и в скором времени получаете брешь в безопасности вашей системы.

Если вы хотите подставлять дополнительное условие, формирование строки через "гуанокод", как выразился @Ипатьев, это путь в дикое усложнение кода, в котором Вы обязательно сделаете где-нибудь ошибку.

Правильно для построения запросов в подобных случаях пользоваться Query Builder (можете найти на github, их там тьма, вот например [pixie](https://github.com/usmanhalalit/pixie)). Они работают по следующему принципу:

```
$query = QB::table('table')
->where('money', '=', 10)
->groupBy(array('table.status'));

if ($condition) {
    $query->andWhere('status', '=', 1);
}
```

Comment: Я бы поставил плюс, если бы в ответе был пример решения проблемы автора вопроса. Но в данный момент такого примера в ответе нет, что делает его ценность нулевой.

Comment: @Ипатьев решение выражено в строках кода и в предложении библиотеки и даже куска кода с нее, который переписан на авторский запрос. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @Firepro в чём заключается SQL-инъекция, если я просто подставляю строку в запрос, без использования каких-либо переменных?

Comment: проблема в том что условие ->andWhere('status', '=', 1) является необязательным. иначе просто нет смысла выносить его из запроса. Если подумать ;)

Comment: @Ипатьев я как бы рассчитывал на то, что автор и сам сможет додумать до такой конструкции, это слишком элементарно :) Исправил ответ. $condition надеюсь мне придумывать не надо? ;)

Comment: @XenK в этом случае уязвимости не будет, да и вообще при аккуратном обращении со строками и использовании правильных функций вы не сможете допустить что-то подобное, но раз на раз не приходиться, где-то в строку название колонки подставили от пользователя и забыли сделать экранирование, и вот брешь в безопасности. Это хоть звучит глупо, но такие случаи есть.

Comment: Переход на квери билдер для основной массы пользователей похапешечки является непреодолимым препятствием сам по себе. Но для тех, кто не смотря ни на что решится на столь отчаянное предприятие, лучше все-таки хоть немного подсластить пилюлю, показав наглядный пример. Спасибо.

Comment: @Ипатьев эх.. так эта же часть "интернетах" начитается статеек от архитекторов ПО с 100500 лет стажа, почему чистый SQL всегда лучше Query Builder'ов и ORM и не перейдут все равно :D

Answer (score -1):

```
$and = 'AND `status` = 1';
$data = array('m' => 10, 'and' => $and);
$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE money=:m AND date(`date`)='2016-08-11':and");
$res->execute($data);
```

Comment: Не стоит отвечать, если не имеешь понятия, как работает твой код.

Comment: @Ипатьев харашо